# Adding new row to igx grid using igx-action-strip

Tags: angular, infragistics, ignite-ui, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I am trying to create a igx grid table with an edit-button, similar to this example provided by Infragistics [Angular Grid Row Adding Example](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/row-adding)

```
<igx-action-strip #actionstrip>
    <igx-grid-editing-actions [addRow]="true"></igx-grid-editing-actions>
</igx-action-strip>
```

I added *IgxActionStripModule* to the *app.modules.ts* and `addRow` is not found. Should I add some other modules or why this simple example does not work?
I did not find no tutorials or explanations about it.
I have Angular version 12 and Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure the following:

- the other two dependency modules are present as well. You should see IgxActionStripModule, IgxInputGroupModule and IgxFocusModule.
- check that the modules persist in the @NgModule imports as well.
- Set rowEditable grid input to true, and add action strip as content projection in the grid:

  <igx-action-strip #actionstrip>
  <igx-grid-editing-actions [addRow]="true">
- Setting primary key is mandatory for row adding operations.

Now upon row hover you should see the row action icons for row adding, editing and delete

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem.

Comment: I'm glad that I helped